# Is it possible to associate Twilio CallSid with PIN code?

Tags: twilio, twilio-programmable-voice

In an app, the users are required to enter a 6 digits PIN to join a conference.
Before the user calls the conference number, the PIN is assigned to a specific user ID.
I would like that after the user enters the PIN, Twilio to pass the CallSid to my app, along with the PIN entered.
Is this possible?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Twilio is passing `CallSid` along with the PIN.

Comment: @AlexBaban can you show where/when?  
I was expected to receive this information in the statusCallback event

Comment: I would like to help you but I don't even know what language are you using and you did not post any code. But, the same way you work with `Digits` to get the PIN, you have `CallSid`.

Comment: Actually you gave me a good hint @AlexBaban. after `gather` step, Twilio provides the `Digits` entered by the user, along with the `CallSid`.